# What php html tokenizer's can I use?

Tags: php, html, tokenize

I need to process html submitted in my web application and don't want to munge the whole thing with regular expressions.  What tokenizer approach and/or software should I take?

Comment: What did you end up using?

Comment: DOMDocument and the various xPath style methods you can apply on top of that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the [DOMDocument::loadHTML method](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) to load the HTML document. And if you want a simpler handling than the DOMDocument methods, you can convert it to a SimpleXML object by using [`simplexml_import_dom()`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-import-dom.php).

Comment: DOMDocument is nice but it autofixes malformed HTML which I don't want. I wish there was something that parsed the input as-is and threw an error on incorrect syntax.

Comment: Also, if the text is directly inside body, it automatically wraps it in <p> tag, which is just too much autocorrection.